# Read and write multiple columns using numpy

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, curve-fitting

I have a txt file where each column is a single measurement. I have a piece of code that smooths this data out using a gaussian filter but it only does this on a single column and then writes a text file with a single column. I would like to loop through each column perform the gaussian filter and eventually write a new txt file where each column is the gaussian filter from the corresponding column in the original text file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

shrinkage = np.loadtxt('dilato_sample_data.txt', skiprows=1).T
smoothed = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(shrinkage, 10)

np.savetxt('smoothed_data.txt', np.c_[time, smoothed])
```

Here is a sample of my original data:

```
Dilato 1 (Lateral)  Dilato 1 (Vertical) Dilato 2 (Lateral)  Dilato 2 (Vertical) 
1   1.01298701298701    1.02197802197802    1.02127659574468
0.987654320987654   1.01298701298701    1.02197802197802    1.03191489361702
0.975308641975309   1   1.02197802197802    1.03191489361702
0.975308641975309   1   1.02197802197802    1.02127659574468
0.962962962962963   1   1.02197802197802    1.02127659574468
0.962962962962963   0.987012987012987   1.02197802197802    1.02127659574468
0.950617283950617   0.987012987012987   1.02197802197802    1.02127659574468
0.938271604938272   0.974025974025974   1.02197802197802    1.02127659574468
0.938271604938272   0.974025974025974   1.02197802197802    1.03191489361702
0.925925925925926   0.974025974025974   1.02197802197802    1.02127659574468
0.91358024691358    0.961038961038961   1.02197802197802    1.02127659574468
0.91358024691358    0.961038961038961   1.02197802197802    1.02127659574468
0.91358024691358    0.961038961038961   1.02197802197802    1.02127659574468
0.901234567901235   0.948051948051948   1.02197802197802    1.02127659574468
0.91358024691358    0.961038961038961   1.02197802197802    1.03191489361702
0.91358024691358    0.948051948051948   1.02197802197802    1.02127659574468
0.888888888888889   0.948051948051948   1.01098901098901    1.02127659574468
0.888888888888889   0.948051948051948   1.02197802197802    1.02127659574468
0.888888888888889   0.935064935064935   1.01098901098901    1.02127659574468
0.888888888888889   0.948051948051948   1.02197802197802    1.02127659574468
0.888888888888889   0.935064935064935   1.01098901098901    1.02127659574468
0.901234567901235   0.935064935064935   1.01098901098901    1.02127659574468
0.888888888888889   0.922077922077922   1.01098901098901    1.01063829787234
0.888888888888889   0.922077922077922   1.01098901098901    1.01063829787234
0.888888888888889   0.922077922077922   1.01098901098901    1.01063829787234
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- Load the file using Pandas as a `DataFrame` and perform the gaussian filter operation on each column using `apply`, and write back to a csv or text file, OR (if you don't want to use Pandas)
- After loading the text file, split all the text in to different lists and perform the gaussian filter operation on each list separately with a for loop. This would be a little inefficient, but it depends if you are after a one-off process with limited resources or not.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I am quite the novice. Pandas sounds more exciting but looking into the libraries I'm already lost. I tried making my own for loop but I'm stuck with how you would split the file into different lists. I've never taken a programming class in my life, I'm just trying to learn as I go.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @vk1011 for your suggestion. I was able to figure out a method using `pandas` and the `apply` function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage
import sys
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv

df = pd.read_csv('dilato_data_all.csv')

def gaussian(x):
    smoothed = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(x, 5)
    return(smoothed)

result_gaussian = df.apply(gaussian, axis=0)
result_gaussian.to_csv('gaussian_result.csv', index=True, header=True)
```